# Can I enter Thailand without having my passport stamped?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, regulations, thailand, passport-stamps, saudi-citizens

Saudi Arabia and Thailand have no political relations due to the bizarre [blue diamond affair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Diamond_Affair). If my passport found to have a Thai stamp during renewal I will be fined some big fine and my passport will be suspended for up to a year.

**Q: Do Thai immigrations do stamps on the landing card without stamping the passport if I ask for it?**

Comment: I would rather "lose" my passport than not going to Thailand :-)

Comment: @greg121 not when you are a crew member and your passport means your job :)

Comment: I can get a second passport, don't know about Saudi Arabia.

Comment: @greg121 not here, if the passport is suspended it means it will be suspended in the system. I will have my passport with me but I can't leave the country.

Comment: I know it happens because I've known people who have done it, mostly through Malaysian travel agencies. It, however, remains in a somewhat gray area of the law, so tread carefully.

Comment: @SystemDown Can you explain more?

Comment: @HaLaBi - I'm afraid I don't have the full details. I know that they travel to Malaysia. From there they contact what seems to me to be shady travel agents who probably bribe Thai passport officials into placing the entry stamps outside of the passport.

Comment: @SystemDown I'd prefer paying the fine but not paying this kind of travel agents who will most probably steal me..

Comment: @HaLaBi - Yeah it did sound extremely seedy to me, and I would never personally risk it.

Comment: If you're going through a major airport you probably have no chance, but might be worth asking. If you're crossing a land border with a local guide it might happen for shady reasons as mentioned above -- but Thailand are pretty strict about entry/exit procedure ... Could you not accidentally leave your passport in some clothes and wash them just before renewal ... hope it washes out the stamps. (NOTE, I'm pretty sure deliberately defacing a passport is an offence). Some countries are changing their policy to use separate paper, but not Thailand as far as I can find out.

Comment: So you are saying if someone with a Saudi passport went to Thailand even for a medical procedure - he will have to pay fine ? For making an attempt to fix some part of the body ?

Comment: @HaLaBi You didnt. I assumed and I thought that would be the case. Glad only tourism is no allowed.

Comment: If you get an actual visa (instead of the stamp on arrival), it's a full page paste-in. As noted in other questions it may be physically possible to remove such a visa. That's probably, um, less than entirely legal ... Zeek's Answer seems like your best bet.

Comment: @MeNoTalk I guess greg's idea is to get two passports, “loose” (destroy or hide) the one with the thai stamp before anyone in Saudi Arabia can look at it and fine/punish you and use the second passport to come back home and renew your passport when you need it.

Comment: @relaxed can't do that, we are allowed to have passport only, and loosing a passport here is even worse than having Thailand's stamp.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an illegal action.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two ways for Saudis to travel legally to Thailand:

### First Way

Get a paper from "Chamber of Commerce" indicating that you have business in Thailand. keep it with you until the renewal, and it's easy to get.

**Conditions**:

1. You should have Establishment([Commercial Register](http://mci.gov.sa/en/ServicesDirectory/Pages/IssuanceofCommercialRegister.aspx)), now you can have Establishment without Location, or you can use your relatives Establishment if someone have one.
2. You shouldn't apply if you are a Government Employee in Civil Affairs.

if this conditions are applied on you, continue reading the first way, otherwise move on to the Second Way :)

Now you just have to go to "Chamber of Commerce"
and give them this printout papers of the following:

1. Your Passport.
2. National ID card.
3. Commercial Register.
4. Chamber of Commerce subscription.
5. Apply for form in Chamber of Commerce(you will find it there).

They will contact "General Directorate of Passports" directly to check if you are not Government Employee then they will give you the permission.

### Second Way

Get a paper from "Ministry of Health" or "Emara" indicating that you are going to Thailand for medical issues. *Any Medical Report will help here*, for example headache, lower back pain. And try to have invitation from physical therapy from Thailand and apply it to nearest "Emara" (BUT YOU SHOULD FOLLOW UP WITH THEM A LOT) because they are slow.

Thailand up to a few years ago was stamping on external paper, but it seems they stopped that now so don't count on it.

Comment: How to get the permission from the chamber of commerce? shouldn't I have a business under my name?

Comment: Would be useful to add an explanation of both procedures: how does one go about getting such authorisations?

Comment: I updated the answer with more details, and it's Easy to have Establishment under your name today most of things can be done online now.

Comment: @Majed Good job, you have my +1. Also, I reformatted you answer using titles, feel free to rollback if you want. ;) Just a quick clarification: what do you mean by `You should have Establishment`? Do you mean that you should have a registered company in Saudi Arabia? Or in Thailand?

Comment: thank you JoErNanO, not it's company, just Establishment which is usually owned by one person. and it have to be Saudi Establishment.

Comment: hi JoErNanO, we Call Establishment for a private Company owned by one person to do any kind of business

Comment: so Establishment is common expression in Saudi Arabia and we don't call them "companies" because company in Saudi Arabia must be owned by more than one person and it have complected thing, but Establishment have easier things, you can start having Establishment from here http://mci.gov.sa/en/ServicesDirectory/Pages/IssuanceofCommercialRegister.aspx

Answer (score 9):

If you are going to Thailand because of work, you can try to get it approved. I've read somewhere that "Personal business visits have to be authorized by the Chamber of Commerce and Industry." It seems like if you are going there because you work on an aircraft that is flying there, it would count as "personal business".

[Ministry of Commerce and Industry](http://www.mci.gov.sa/en/Pages/Default.aspx) (Saudi Arabia)

Comment: I am going for pleasure actually..

Comment: Rather than providing a link to a general website, could you try finding the relevant page? Also it would be useful to quote the important bits of information found on the website, in your answer. This is because links are not immutable objects and tend to vary/disappear-into-404-oblivion over time. ;)